# Как добавить словарь для elasticsearch который создан из оператора?

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift

Установил Elasticsearch 7.17 в openshift из  Operators , 3 пода. Надо добавить словарь hunspell для каждого пода.   Для хранения использую PVC

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 50Gi
            storageClassName: storagecluster-rbd
            volumeMode: Filesystem
          status: {}
```

Скопировать каталог с файлами словаря не подходит так как после перезапуска пода файлы словаря пропадают.